# Control nested for-loops Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nested-loops

This must be simple for whoever has experience I guess. All I am trying to do is to put together in an array of dictionaries the days of the month with their respective days of the week using nested `for`-loops.

For example:

I create an instance of the array like so:

```
let arrayOfDictionaries:[[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()
```

I later create an array of the days of the week:

```
let daysOfWeek = ["Monday","Tuesday"..."Sunday"]
```

Then I have a for loop for the 31 days of the month of October, with `for` loop inside regarding the days of the week:

```
for i in 1...31 {
  for day in daysOfWeek{
     arrayOfDictionaries.append(["Monday",1])
     ....
  }
}
```

At the end I want to end up with `arrayOfDictionaries` looking like so (Assuming October would start on a Monday):

> [["Monday",1],["Tuesday",2]...["Monday",8],["Tuesday",9]...["Monday",16],["Tuesday",17]...and so on up to the 31st]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `[["Monday",1],["Tuesday",2]...` I hope you don't think that is an array of dictionaries. It is an array of arrays. So typing `arrayOfDictionaries` as `[[String:Any]]` makes no sense. And neither does your question; it is utterly unclear what you want to do. Do you even know? (Also you cannot append to something declared with `let`.)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This data structure seems astoundingly convoluted.

Comment: Does either answer do what you need? If not, please clarify your question. If one of the answers does solve your issue, please indicate this by accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using the modulo operator!

```
var arrayOfDictionaries:[[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()
let daysOfWeek = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]


for i in 1...31 {
    arrayOfDictionaries.append([daysOfWeek[((i - 1) % 7)]:i])
}
```

Comment: This only works for months that happen to start on a Monday.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what OP was asking for. He can take this logic and apply it to suit his needs if he'll be using other months too.

Comment: But October 1, 2016 is Saturday, not Monday.

Comment: @rmaddy Valid point, but I just answered the question exactly as OP asked it. There is no mention of what year they are working with, nor do they ask for a way to calculate what day the first day of the month is. At face value, this question is purely asking about using loops to create ["Monday":1],["Tuesday":2]... etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Reece. Its exactly what I was looking for...and as you said I never asked specifically for what month or what day the month started with. I was interested in the syntax of the code.

Comment: @SebastianSerrano You're welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

A few issues.

1. Your array of dictionary should be `[[Int:String]]` since you want the key to be the day of the month and you want its value to be the weekday corresponding to that date.
2. Don't build your own list of weekdays. `DateFormatter` provides such a list.
3. You first need to calculate the weekday for the 1st of the month you are working with.
4. You don't need nested loops.

Given that, the following code should be what you are looking for:

```
let day = 1
let month = 10
let year = 2016
var components = DateComponents()
components.year = year
components.month = month
components.day = day
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) // date for October 1, 2016
let dow = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date!) // 7 for Saturday

let daysOfWeek = DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols as [String] // Get the localized list of weekdays

var arrayOfDictionaries:[[Int:String]] = []
for i in 1...31 {
    arrayOfDictionaries.append([i : daysOfWeek[(i + dow - 2) % 7]])
}

print(arrayOfDictionaries)
```

The output is:

> [[1: "Saturday"], [2: "Sunday"], [3: "Monday"], [4: "Tuesday"], [5: "Wednesday"], [6: "Thursday"], [7: "Friday"], [8: "Saturday"], [9: "Sunday"], [10: "Monday"], [11: "Tuesday"], [12: "Wednesday"], [13: "Thursday"], [14: "Friday"], [15: "Saturday"], [16: "Sunday"], [17: "Monday"], [18: "Tuesday"], [19: "Wednesday"], [20: "Thursday"], [21: "Friday"], [22: "Saturday"], [23: "Sunday"], [24: "Monday"], [25: "Tuesday"], [26: "Wednesday"], [27: "Thursday"], [28: "Friday"], [29: "Saturday"], [30: "Sunday"], [31: "Monday"]]

Comment: For sure this also answers the question very well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You would have saved a lot of people a lot of time if you had clarified your question and properly explained what you needed.

Comment: I understand...will do next time!